# NHibernate accumulate queryOver conditions

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I want to do a sort of filtering chain to filter Receipt objects using queryOver functionality.
The chain can differ in length, according to the parameters user chooses on the screen.

Eventually, I want the chain to run somehow like this:

```
public IList<Receipt> RunFilters()
{
    IQueryOver<Receipt, Receipt> currQuery = NHibernateHelper.Session.QueryOver<Receipt>();

    foreach (var item in filters)
    {
        currQuery = item.RunFilter(currQuery);
    }
    return currQuery.List();
}
```

So, the question is - how RunFilter should be defined? I thought it should be

```
public IQueryOver<Receipt, Receipt> RunFilter(IQueryOver<Receipt, Receipt> prevFilter)
```

and they I can do filters like

```
return prevFilter.Where(receipt => receipt.TotalSum > 0);
```

But I can't do

```
return prevFilter.JoinQueryOver(v => v.Store).Where(vv => vv.Name.Equals(m_storeName));
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return prevFilter.JoinQueryOver(v => v.Store).Where(vv => vv.Name.Equals(m_storeName));
```

the above can be written as

```
Store storeAlias = null;
return prevFilter.JoinAlias(v => v.Store, () => storeAlias).Where(() => storeAlias.Name == m_storeName);
```

EDIT: fixed equation

Comment: Thanks! I got an exception when I copied it as is, but after I changed  storeAlias.Name.Equals to storeAlias.Name == ... it worked.